# Launch application process in the background

Tags: c#, winforms, google-chrome, setforegroundwindow

I have created a Windows Forms app that listens to keyboard input. When the correct input command is entered it should launch an instance of google chrome which will then run a chrome extension that I have developed.

I want the chrome process to run quietly in the background whilst other foreground processes run if possible. Or if this is not possible then I want to be able to swap back to the process that was active in the foreground before the command was successfully input.

Is this at all possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This:

```
    private void MainForm_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        Log("MainForm_KeyUp");
        if (e.Control && e.KeyCode == Keys.P)
        {
            Process.Start("chrome.exe", "http://www.your_website_url.com");
         } 

    }
```

Make sure you will set  [keypreview property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.keypreview.aspx) of the form  to true

Vaibhav Tapare

Comment: This work but they do not launch the application in the background, which is what I really want. I am already using Process.Start to launch but it always takes over the foreground

Answer (score 0):

have you tried something like:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        var Process = new Process
        {
            StartInfo =
            {
                FileName = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\Chrome.exe",
                WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal
            }
        };


        Process.Start();

        Console.ReadKey();

    }
```

Comment: This still launches chrome in the foreground unfortunately